# How to verify custom Firebase Auth Token, created by createCustomToken()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I created custom Auth Token via createCustomToken(), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens.

But later on when I try to verify this token via verifyIdToken() function it  throws following error

```
Error: verifyIdToken() expects an ID token, but was given a custom token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
```

Which is rational, because there is no such ID... But what I need - is to simply verify the token, similar to jwt.verify()...

Has anyone came across this problem and what solution was found? Is it possible to verify Firebase auth token via jsonwebtoken library?

P.S. I am gonna use verification in Google Cloud Function endpoints

SOLUTION: Looks like I just found a solution https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library Just need to grap public key from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com and use jsonwebtoken library to verify it...

Answer (score 2):

`verifyIdToken` like the name is to verify `IdToken`, not custom token.

CustomToken is for client to `sign in`. This custom token can be verify using simple JWT verification like your solution (it expire after one hour).

But the `IdToken` is another story, you need to do sign in process using firebase auth.

To Get The `Id Token` from client **after signIn**, it's depend whether the client is Android, Web, or IOS.
The code to get the `IdToken` can be read in [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

Comment: The reason is that you can verify ANY token if you know its encryption public key. The difference is that verifyIdToken also checks users presence in the Users Table. In my case I didn't want to either check users presence in the Users Table or Sign In with a new CustomToken to create a new user in the Users Table. Anyway I found alternative solution for my particular case. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @Timothy, I am facing similar requirement "In my case I didn't want to either check users presence in the Users Table or Sign In with a new CustomToken to create a new user in the Users Table". Would you mind comment how you did in your case or answer one of my questons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355351/angular-and-firestore-firebaseerror-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-how-a

Comment: Same question I posted here https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2419