# Angular and Firestore: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. How add idToken while observing a specific document

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, token

I code the code bellow that is notified in real time manner. I mean it keeps observing and soon any collection fields are updated it is loaded in Angular page.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.transfers = db.collection('/transfer').valueChanges();
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let transfer of transfers | async">
    <pre>{{ transfer | json }}</pre>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add an idToken while observing with either  db.collection().valueChanges() or snapshotChanges(). Well, I know how generate the idToken outside the application from a Custom Token and for this question I want to focus only how to add such idToken while "listening" valueChanges() or snapshotChanges() of a specific document. Imagine each document is a diferent transaction interested only to a single user.

The above code works as expected if I change the Firestore rules to "allow read to all" but I want to find someway to only allow Angular to read if it pass the idToken and, on top of that, observe single document changes instead of observe all documents from an entire collection as code above does.

Here are some tentatives failling just to exemplify what I am trying. I don't know how to add idToken in any of them. I added also an example what I am imagining could work without AngularFire. I guess I am confused about three points here:

- some very basic idea how to observe/listen a single document
- how add a idToken similar as I do with curl/postman
- it isn't possible to listen/observe a single document. I must observe entire collection and filter.

Tentative 1:

```
this.uniqueTransfer = db.collection('/transfer',
  ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1"))
  .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()))
  );;
```

Tentative 2:

```
this.uniqueTransfer = db.collection('/transfer', ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1")).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    return { data };
  }))
```

Tentative 3:

```
db.doc(`transfer/Wsj0dysyHHok3xupwDhD`) //this is the id copied from Firebase console
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe()
  .subscribe();
```

Tentative 4 without AngularFire

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.getTranfers();
}

public getTranfers() {

  const headers = { 'Authorization': 'valid idtoken working with curl' }
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    "structuredQuery": {
      "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
          "field": { "fieldPath": "id" },
          "op": "EQUAL",
          "value": { "stringValue": "4" }
        }
      },
      "from": [{ "collectionId": "transfer" }]
    }
  })

  this.http.post<any>('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firetestjimis/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery', body, { headers }).subscribe(data => {
    this.uniqueTransfer = data;
  })
}
```

And the expected behaviour is listening for a especific document be changed and update front end like:

```
<div>{{(uniqueTransfer|async)?.status}}</div>
```

Finally, in case it adds here, I can query a single document with this curl. Obvisouly it is not listening/observing the document. It just retrieves it.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firetestjimis/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer certain idToken resulted from a Custom Token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"structuredQuery": {
    "where" : {
        "fieldFilter" : { 
        "field": {"fieldPath": "id"}, 
        "op":"EQUAL", 
        "value": {"stringValue": "1"}
        }
    },
    "from": [{"collectionId": "transfer"}]
    }
}'
```

*** edited After gso_Gabriel's two suggestions.

FIRST SUGGESTION)

I tried follow https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2109. Well it seems to be a suggestion for new feature than really a current alternative. BTW, I gave a try with:

```
this.transfers = db.doc<any>(`transfer/sDme6IRIi4ezfeyfrU7y`).valueChanges();
```

sDme6IRIi4ezfeyfrU7y stands for a specific document but I got all documents from transfer collection (same behaviour as this.transfers = db.collection('/transfer').valueChanges();)

SECOND SUGGESTION)

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;
  uniqueTransfer: any;

  transferCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {

    this.transferCollectionRef = db.collection<any>('transfer', ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1"));
    this.transfers = this.transferCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data();// as Todo;
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
}
```

This worked. I can see the filter "where" is applied (...  ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1")

Now I am missing how to use the idToken resulted from Custom Tokem. I guess it must exist someway like we do with HttpClient (see my Tentative 4 above to understand what is common approach with header).

*** In case it add somehow here, even the similar question posted on github didn't get any comment other than someone saying is looking for same answer https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2419

*** FINAL SOLUTION THANKS TO gstvg

```
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;

  transferCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.listenSingleTransferWithToken();
  }

  async listenAllTransfersWithToken() {
    await this.auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJh...w8l-NO-rw");
    this.transfers = this.db.collection('/transfer').valueChanges();
  }

  async listenSingleTransferWithToken() {
    await this.auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJ...w8l-NO-rw");
    this.transferCollectionRef = this.db.collection<any>('transfer', ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1"));
    this.transfers = this.transferCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data();
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @JimC as indicated in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2109) in the repository from Angular, you can send a specific value, to return a single document within a observable. You can do that for an entire collection, not to a single document. In addition to that, I found this nice tutorial [here](https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/) of how to return single documents - seems to be a workaround - while using observables. Could you please give it a try and let me know if this helps?

Comment: @gso_gabriel, your first link seems to be a proposal, not yet available. Well, I read "This currently only works when working with a collection() call.

It may also be nice to do the same when reading a single doc() like so:

const taskId = 'abcdefg';
const task: Observable<Task> = this.firestore.doc<Task>(`tasks/${taskId}`).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });" . It is somehow close to my third tentative. And your second link seems quite close to  my tentative 2. BTW, I will try carefully each one again. Meanwhile, do you know I add a token with snapshotChanges ou valueChanges method?

Comment: Hi @JimC I believe it's not possible to send a token/variable in the `snapshotChanges()`/`valueChanges()` methods. However, could you please edit the question and the full error message that you are facing? This way, I should have a better view on the specific error.

Comment: @gso_gabriel thanks, your second suggestion fixed the issue to listen a single document. But how would you use Custom Token from Front End while observing a either a whole Collection or a single Document? The error pasted in my question topic is exactly the error I get if I enable a rule in Firestore to allow READ only with TOKEN ... (match /{document=**} {
      allow read, update, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

Comment: Hi @JimC there isn't much a way to send the token from front end. I believe using the workaround would be the best approach for you, for now. Another option I would recommend you would be to reach out directly to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support), so they can provide a deeper insight on this (they have free support tier).

Comment: How would you do if you were my case, I mean, Mobile listen/observe to Collection and you CAN'T create an user for each user. You only can create an user for Mobile Application in Firestore. To sum up, it will work that way: there will be one POST endpoint in our company servers. When a mobile user post a transfer it will reach this company server and receive back a transfer id. After that, mobile application will GET and start to OBSERVE  a Firestore endpoint listening for status update. I was planning return both transfer id and some idtoken that it would be used during GET to Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firestore client auth is handled by firebase auth, so, to make authenticated calls, you must authenticate with firebase auth on the frontend, with your custom token generated on the backend, using firebase.auth.signinWithCustomToken(customToken):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore, public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    await auth.signinWithCustomToken(customToken);
    this.transfers = db.collection('/transfer').valueChanges();
  }

}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcustomtoken

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md