# How to authenticate a cloud function in a remote API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to protect an API endpoint that is used by a Firebase cloud function. My plan was to use the authentication system of Firebase by using custom tokens generated in Firebase with the `createCustomToken()` method, send them with the Authorization header and then validate those in the API. I tried doing this with `verifyIdToken()` but it turns out that this is the wrong approach.

How can I validate custom tokens in my API, or what is the recommended approach here?

Comment: "but it turns out that this is the wrong approach" Why is that? It seems pretty much what is suggested here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: ID Tokens are only useful for client authentication, not for the scenario I have in mind. ID Tokens are linked to a user that authenticated in Firebase, but the API does not do that.

Comment: Are you asking [how to authenticate server to server API calls](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+authenticate+server+to+server+API+calls)?

Comment: No, I was asking if there is a best practice to do this with Google Cloud Functions and not how to do this in general.

Comment: can you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550686/15774176) and [answer_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758804/15774176) , [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776966/15774176) , are these helpful?